# Selecting text in a fillable Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I've created a fillable template form in Word.  When I am filling in the form, and decide to edit a word, I cannot just select that word.  Everything in the fillable box ends up getting selected instead of just that individual word.  How do I just select 1 word or sentence without the entire text in that box getting selected?

Answer (score 0):

### What you are using are "legacy" form fields and the legacy protection method for "Filling in Forms." As long as you use those, you cannot easily edit.

Use Content Controls and either the Group Control protection or the No Changes - with exceptions protection method.

Here is Greg Maxey's page on [making forms using Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_fillin_form.html).

There are utilities available that convert legacy form fields to content controls. Here is one free utility: [Content Control Tools](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html) by Greg Maxey.